# Two buttons with equal width horizontally fill the screen in React Native

Tags: react-native, button, view

I need to create two or more buttons which will be of equal **width** and **horizontally aligned**, based on screen width button width may vary.

[image: Sample Image Here]

Comment: what is the button width ?

Comment: Not fixed, It depends on its parent view width.

Comment: Ok so we need, width = deviceWidth/number of buttons. I think that's cool

Comment: Yep, flex is working fine for View but the same doesn't works with Button.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can wrap you Buttons into flexed Views :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default const FlexedButtons () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
     <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
      <Button title="Button 1"/>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
      <Button title="Button 2"/>
    </View>
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  }
});
```

Here is a working example on Sketch:
https://snack.expo.io/SyMpPSise

Comment: working with react-native-elements button, i had to remove the `flex:1` on the container and it worked fine thx.

Comment: I spent hours looking how to do this! I didnt have to remove the `flex: 1` using react-native-elements however.

Comment: Using it "pure" I had to remove flex:1 on the container

Answer (score 3):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

export default class ButtonExample extends Component {
  _onPressButton() {
    alert('You tapped the button!')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Button
            onPress={this._onPressButton}
            title="Press Me"
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Button
            onPress={this._onPressButton}
            title="Press Me"
            color="#841584"
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.alternativeLayoutButtonContainer}>
          <Button
            onPress={this._onPressButton}
            title="This looks great!"
          />
          <Button
            onPress={this._onPressButton}
            title="OK!"
            color="#841584"
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
   flex: 1,
   justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    margin: 20
  },
  alternativeLayoutButtonContainer: {
    margin: 20,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
  }
});
```

[image]

```
 <View style={styles.menuContainer}>

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.pressLink('Home')}>
                 <View style={styles.imageTextContainer}>
                      <Image
                       source={require('./on.png')} />
                      <Text style={{flex:1 ,color: '#fff',fontSize: 20,marginLeft: 20}} >Home</Text>
                 </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>

              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.pressLink('About')}>

                 <View style={styles.imageTextContainer}>
                      <Image
                       source={require('./on.png')} />
                      <Text style={{flex:1 ,color: '#fff',fontSize: 20,marginLeft: 20}} >About</Text>
                 </View>

              </TouchableOpacity>
           </View>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  menuContainer: {
    flex: 0.52,
    marginLeft: 5
  },
  imageTextContainer: {
      marginLeft: 20,
      padding: 10,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-between'
  }
});
```

[image]